# Get the current url in a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

How can i get the full curent url wether it https or https in a mysql query like below ?

```
AND `url` = 'http://.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];'
```

As the above part does not work

Complete string , i want to add this at the end with AND :

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_online WHERE `customer_id` != '0' AND date_added > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ");
```

Comment: Show us all your php please.

Comment: Have you tried `echo $sql;` to see what query is being sent to MySQL?

Comment: Can you post the complete sql statement, there is definitely something wrong with the way you are concatenating strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public function getRegisteredUsersOnline(){ 
 $url = "http".(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?"s":"")."//".
        $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

   $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_online WHERE customer_id != '0' AND `date_added` > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
   AND `url` = ?");
   $query->execute( array( $url ) );
   $count = $query->fetch(2);
   return $count['num'];

}
```

Comment: How do i modify this then ? `public function getRegisteredUsersOnline(){
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_online WHERE `customer_id` != '0' AND date_added > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ");
  
  return $query->rows;
 }`

Comment: public function getRegisteredUsersOnline(){
  $url = "http".(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?"s":"")."://".
        $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_online WHERE `customer_id` != '0' AND date_added > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND url = '$url'");
  
  return $query->rows;
 }

This worked a treat.
Thanx for your help though.